# How do I make my php login page actually login?

Tags: php, sql, authentication

So I have had enough of this assignment, I am still trying to make this login page actually login, it supposed to be a self referring login page using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] but it still will not do ANYTHING

```
<center>
<h2>Please log in</h2>
<p>Enter your login ID and password to connect to this system<br/>
</p>
<form name="Input" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table border="1" bgcolor="black" cellpadding="10" >
<tr>
    <td><strong>Username:</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="login" value="" size="20" placeholder="Username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Password:</strong></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" size="20" placeholder="**********"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellspacing="15" >
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value = "Login" /></td>

    <td><input type="reset" value = "Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<p>
Please wait after pressing <strong>Log in</strong>
while we retrieve your records from our database.<br/>
<em>(This may take a few moments)</em>
</p>
<hr/>
</center>
</body>
</html>

<?php   //embed in a page with a two input box (named id and pass) form
    require "functions.php";
    $login = $_POST['id'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $conn = db_connect();
    $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email_address, last_access FROM   users WHERE id = '".$login."' AND password= '".$password."'";
    $results = pg_query($conn, $sql);
    if(pg_num_rows($results)){  //not zero means something was found
//user found, use pg_fetch_result to pull user specific info to displa
    }else{
        //user not found, check for just login id
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE id = '".$login."'";
        $results = pg_query($conn, $sql);
         if(!pg_num_rows($results)){  //user not found, empty $login to unstick it
            $login = ""; //when echo’’ed in the form
        }
    }
```

This is the code I already have

This is the code my teacher gave in class but it still doesnt work

I also don't know where to put the welcome message or how to get it to show up.

Ive tried making a welcome.php file with the welcome message but it still doesn't work

There's just something I'm missing

(Also if you choose to comment dont be rude about it, I'm struggling)

Thanks

?>

Comment: Have you tried by our own?

Comment: Yes if I didnt I wouldnt have posted the question -_- I've been working on this for two weeks now trying to figure it out

Comment: two weeks for a simple login system?

Comment: Yup, like I said I cant figure out why it won't login

Comment: Need to see all files. not a single one. its need debugging. if you want, i can help you remotely.

Comment: Sure we could do that I'd appreciate it

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is pretty vague. What isn't working, specifically? What is your environment? What does your database look like, and are you able to successfully connect to it? I recommend breaking the problem down into small chunks: 1. make sure you can post data to the server, 2. make sure you can connect to the database, 3. check whether your query is successful by looking at the db, 4. try redirecting the user upon successful authentication to your welcome page.

Comment: it's not logging in can't get anymore specific than that. Like Im pretty sure it's connecting to the database but I'm not sure, I'm using winscp and pgadmin for all this stuff

Comment: OK, that's helpful. I'd recommend editing your question to include that info, and you need to establish exactly what isn't working, otherwise we can only make guesses about it. See [mcve] for more information about writing a good SO question.

Comment: give me your anydesk software id

Comment: I dont have anydesk. I dont know what that is

Comment: You have a username field yet you are not doing anything with the text entered in that field.

Comment: 'This is the code my teacher gave in class but it still doesnt work' Should you not start by asking your teacher why his/her own code is not working? There may be an error that they have since corrected.

Comment: @MandyShaw I had to change it to fit my database so its something I am doing

Comment: In that case the first thing I would do would be to make sure I could get the teacher's example to work as it stood, then tweak that, rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: I just want the stupid thing to work!

Answer (score 3):

In your PHP code you are trying to get username from `$_POST['Id']` but actualy you field name is `$_POST['login']`

Change your field name correctly, I also suggest you to use `error_reporting()` on development environment, this will help you to debug.

Second, do not save plain password, always encrypt your password.

Your code is open for SQL injection, for preventing use PDO.

One more suggestion, run your PHP script if form submitted or you can use

```
if(count($_POST) > 0){
   //execute code
}
```

One last debugging suggestion, when you are using `<form>` and you think its not working then you must need to check either getting input or not by using:

```
print_r($_POST) // POST / GET
```

this will help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: no the id is from my sql database which is the name of the field for the username and yes I know I will edit all that other stuff once i get it to actually work

Comment: @dianne: but here using id instead of login will not work

Comment: why wont it work?

Comment: Because you r using undefined index for username @dianne

Comment: ok well changed it it still does nothing

Comment: @dianne: follow instructions given in answer, debug $_POST CHk what r u getting, chk you connection, use error_reporting on

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense I don't know how to use that or where to implement it

Comment: @dianne read how can I use Php error_reporting in your code https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_reporting.asp